# How is this Graph called?

Tags: graph, geometry

What could be the name to call a (Circular?) graph made like this:

> (to Last D) <- A <-> B <-> C <-> D -> (to First A)

So the connection between the first and last element closes the graph like a circle.

Thanks and sorry for the maybe stupid question not directly related to programming.

Comment: A cycle graph. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph
Not really a programming question, so I flagged it. Sorry

Comment: thanks Bart, if you wish you can post it as answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [cycle graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph).